# # is added in url instaed of replacing

Tags: url, hash

I added a page displaying Google map in basic MVC4 mobile web app.

here is my url.. http://zenith.iwaywiz.com:8000/MobApp/

this works fine in desktop browser
but when checked in mobile it gives me trouble
when I click on Contact tab the URL is

zenith.iwaywiz.com:8000/MobApp/Home/Contact

now when I click on Map tab the URL changes to

zenith.iwaywiz.com:8000/MobApp/Home/Contact#/MobApp/Home/Map

instead of

zenith.iwaywiz.com:8000/MobApp/Home/Map

This problem occurs only for this page and only in mobile

Can anybody please give me a solution
I'm very new to MVC4 and mobile web development
appreciate suitable answers... thank you...

Comment: jQuery Mobile will use ajax to load page so it append #/MobApp/Home/Map to url is the correct behavior, Your problem may be related to ajax call, is it correctly return?

Comment: no, when url is changed map is not displayed. map is disaplayed if i make url as ../mobapp/home/map. I don't know where to make changes. For other tabs redirect url not including # in it at all